# React : Apply Body overflow on specific component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a react app using `create-react-app`. My file structure is like the following :

```
Index.js
App.css
App.js
-- MyComponent1.js
-- MyComponent2.js
```

To navigate between the two components I'm using `react-router-dom` in `App.js` like this :

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <Route path='/MyComponent1' exact component={MyComponent1} />
        <Route path='/MyComponent2' exact component={MyComponent2} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

So both components are using the same `App.css` style imported in `App.js`

I want to apply an `overflow:hidden` to the body **when I'm only on** `Component1` and remove this new class on other components, how to do so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

All I had to do was using `document.body` directly on the component to set the styles directly using Hook.

So `overflow:visible` will be applied on the component mounting, and `overflow:hidden` on the component unmounting like the following :

```
      useEffect(() => {
// Applying on mount
        document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
// Applying on unmount    
        return () => {
          document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
        }
      }, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

the answear of AlyaKra works.

in my case there are two pages one with oferflow and other without

the solution

```
useEffect(() => {
    // Applying on mount
    document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
    // Applying on unmount
    return () => {
      document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    };   }, []);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).